# How to split rows in SQL Server table into multiple tables

Tags: sql-server

I have a table with more than 1000 records. Here is a sample extract from the table:

```
VersionTested       RunDate          TestName       AverageTime
---------------------------------------------------------------
v.1                20170802-1036     function1        10.02
v.1                20170802-1036     function2        12.36
v.1                20170802-1036     function3        11.36
v.1                20170802-1036     function4        14.36
v.2                20170803-1000     function1        10.06
v.2                20170803-1000     function2        12.36
v.2                20170803-1000     function3        12.00
v.2                20170803-1000     function4        11.02
v.3                20170731-1000     function1        10.02
v.3                20170731-1000     function2        12.36
v.3                20170731-1000     function3        11.02
v.3                20170731-1000     function4        12.56
```

Basically I have 106 functions am running against different `versionTested`. So what I want to do is to compare the average time for each function vs versionTested.

Please see the output am looking for below:

`Function1` table:

```
VersionTested    RunDate        TestName    AverageTime
---------------------------------------------------------
 v.1             20170802-1036  function1    10.02
 v.2             20170803-1000  function1    10.06
 v.3             20170731-1000  function1    10.02
```

function 2 table:

```
 VersionTested    RunDate        TestName    AverageTime
 -------------------------------------------------------
     v.1          20170802-1036  function2    12.36
     v.2          20170803-1000  function2    12.36
     v.3          20170731-1000  function2    12.36
```

I want this kind of scenario to all the 106 functions. How can this be achieved in T-SQL?

The last thing will be plotting graphs of each function against different VersionTested to compare the average times.

How can this be achieved in T-SQL? Probably there is no need to split this information into multiple tables? Any suggestion is welcome.

Here is the code I am busy working on but I dont seem to go anywhere with it:

```
SELECT 'RunDate' AS DateTested, 
        v.1, v.2, v.3
        FROM
        (SELECT *
         FROM TableName) AS SourceTable
        PIVOT
        (
         SUM(VersionTested)
         FOR VersionTested IN (v.1, v.2, v.3)
        ) AS PivotTable;
```

Comment: You are looking to return datasets so that the data can be displayed on a graph, yes? If so, I don't think you need the pivot. Are you going to have a separate graph for each function, or all functions on one graph?

Comment: @Aidan, yes am going to have separate graph for each function. How can this be achieved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1This should do what you'r asking...

```
USE tempdb;
GO

IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb.dbo.FunctionTestAll', 'U') IS NOT NULL 
DROP TABLE dbo.FunctionTestAll;

CREATE TABLE dbo.FunctionTestAll (
    VersionTested CHAR(3) NOT NULL,
    RunDate CHAR(13) NOT NULL,
    TestName CHAR(9) NOT NULL,
    AverageTime DECIMAL(5,2)
    );
INSERT dbo.FunctionTestAll (VersionTested, RunDate, TestName, AverageTime) VALUES
    ('v.1', '20170802-1036', 'function1', 10.02),
    ('v.1', '20170802-1036', 'function2', 12.36),
    ('v.1', '20170802-1036', 'function3', 11.36),
    ('v.1', '20170802-1036', 'function4', 14.36),
    ('v.2', '20170803-1000', 'function1', 10.06),
    ('v.2', '20170803-1000', 'function2', 12.36),
    ('v.2', '20170803-1000', 'function3', 12.00),
    ('v.2', '20170803-1000', 'function4', 11.02),
    ('v.3', '20170731-1000', 'function1', 10.02),
    ('v.3', '20170731-1000', 'function2', 12.36),
    ('v.3', '20170731-1000', 'function3', 11.02),
    ('v.3', '20170731-1000', 'function4', 12.56);
GO

--SELECT * FROM dbo.FunctionTestAll fta

--=========================================================

IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb.dbo.TablesToCreate', 'U') IS NOT NULL 
DROP TABLE dbo.TablesToCreate;

SELECT 
    TestID = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)),
    fta.TestName
    INTO dbo.TablesToCreate
FROM
    dbo.FunctionTestAll fta
GROUP BY
    fta.TestName;

----------------------------------------------------------

DECLARE @TestID INT = 0;

WHILE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM dbo.TablesToCreate ttc WHERE ttc.TestID > @TestID)
BEGIN 
    SET @TestID = @TestID + 1;

    DECLARE @CreateTableSQL VARCHAR(1000) = '';

    SELECT 
        @CreateTableSQL = CONCAT('
CREATE TABLE dbo.', ttc.TestName, ' (
    VersionTested CHAR(3) NOT NULL,
    RunDate CHAR(13) NOT NULL,
    TestName CHAR(9) NOT NULL,
    AverageTime DECIMAL(5,2)
    );

INSERT dbo.', ttc.TestName, ' (VersionTested, RunDate, TestName, AverageTime)
SELECT 
    fta.VersionTested, fta.RunDate, fta.TestName, fta.AverageTime
FROM
    dbo.FunctionTestAll fta
WHERE
    fta.TestName = ''', ttc.TestName, ''';'
        )
    FROM
        dbo.TablesToCreate ttc
    WHERE
        ttc.TestID = @TestID;

    EXEC(@CreateTableSQL);
END;
GO


--  SELECT * FROM dbo.function1;
--  SELECT * FROM dbo.function2;
--  SELECT * FROM dbo.function3;
--  SELECT * FROM dbo.function4;

--  DROP TABLE dbo.function1;
--  DROP TABLE dbo.function2;
--  DROP TABLE dbo.function3;
--  DROP TABLE dbo.function4;
```

HTH, Jason

Answer (score 0):

I was not totally sure what you wanted to see as a resultset.  It is always good when asking a question like this to show not just sample data but also sample output.  I doubled the sample data, so that AVG had a job to do (so we know it's working!).

Because I was not really sure how exactly the pivot should be, I give two versions:

```
declare @versiontests table
(
versiontested char(3),
datetested datetime,
functionname varchar(15),
timetaken float
)
INSERT INTO @versiontests VALUES('v.1','2017-08-02 10:36','function1',10.02)
INSERT INTO @versiontests VALUES('v.1','2017-08-02 10:36','function2',12.36)
INSERT INTO @versiontests VALUES('v.1','2017-08-02 10:36','function3',11.36)
INSERT INTO @versiontests VALUES('v.1','2017-08-02 10:36','function4',14.36)
INSERT INTO @versiontests VALUES('v.2','2017-08-03 10:00','function1',10.06)
INSERT INTO @versiontests VALUES('v.2','2017-08-03 10:00','function2',12.36)
INSERT INTO @versiontests VALUES('v.2','2017-08-03 10:00','function3',12.00)
INSERT INTO @versiontests VALUES('v.2','2017-08-03 10:00','function4',11.02)
INSERT INTO @versiontests VALUES('v.3','2017-07-31 10:00','function1',10.02)
INSERT INTO @versiontests VALUES('v.3','2017-07-31 10:00','function2',12.36)
INSERT INTO @versiontests VALUES('v.3','2017-07-31 10:00','function3',11.02)
INSERT INTO @versiontests VALUES('v.3','2017-07-31 10:00','function4',12.56)
INSERT INTO @versiontests VALUES('v.1','2017-08-02 11:36','function1',10.22)
INSERT INTO @versiontests VALUES('v.1','2017-08-02 11:36','function2',12.31)
INSERT INTO @versiontests VALUES('v.1','2017-08-02 11:36','function3',11.26)
INSERT INTO @versiontests VALUES('v.1','2017-08-02 11:36','function4',14.16)
INSERT INTO @versiontests VALUES('v.2','2017-08-03 11:00','function1',10.56)
INSERT INTO @versiontests VALUES('v.2','2017-08-03 11:00','function2',12.56)
INSERT INTO @versiontests VALUES('v.2','2017-08-03 11:00','function3',12.40)
INSERT INTO @versiontests VALUES('v.2','2017-08-03 11:00','function4',11.22)
INSERT INTO @versiontests VALUES('v.3','2017-07-31 11:00','function1',10.52)
INSERT INTO @versiontests VALUES('v.3','2017-07-31 11:00','function2',12.46)
INSERT INTO @versiontests VALUES('v.3','2017-07-31 11:00','function3',11.09)
INSERT INTO @versiontests VALUES('v.3','2017-07-31 11:00','function4',12.37)

SELECT functionname, datetested, [v.1], [v.2], [v.3]
        FROM
        (SELECT CAST(datetested AS date) as datetested, versiontested, functionname, timetaken
         FROM @versiontests) AS SourceTable
        PIVOT
        (
         AVG(timetaken) FOR versiontested in ([v.1], [v.2], [v.3])
        ) AS PivotTable
        ;
SELECT functionname, [v.1], [v.2], [v.3]
        FROM
        (SELECT versiontested, functionname, timetaken
         FROM @versiontests) AS SourceTable
        PIVOT
        (
         AVG(timetaken) FOR versiontested in ([v.1], [v.2], [v.3])
        ) AS PivotTable
        ;
```

EDIT

Use the same table declaration and inserts as above but instead of PIVOT SELECTS use the following:

```
declare @functionNames table
(
functionname varchar(15),
rownum int
)

INSERT INTO @functionNames 
SELECT d.functionname, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY d.functionname) from 
(SELECT DISTINCT functionname FROM @versiontests) as d

declare @cnt int = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM @functionNames)
declare @rowPtr int = 0
declare @tempFunc varchar(15)


while @rowPtr < @cnt
    begin
        SET @rowPtr = @rowPtr + 1
        SET @tempFunc = (SELECT functionname FROM @functionNames WHERE rownum = @rowPtr)        
        SELECT versiontested, datetested, functionname, timetaken FROM @versiontests
            WHERE functionname = @tempFunc
    end
```

This will split the SELECT up into n separate SELECTS.  If you are using a DataSet (from c# for example) you will get n different DataTables in the DataSet.

I think though that you will want to add some grouping by date to get an average per day, but I leave that to you to figure out.

Comment: I want each function to have its own table and also note that the VersionTested must be dynamic

Comment: Please amend your question to show example end result set (for one function name is enough).  Dynamic VersionTested is only possible with dynamic SQL

Comment: I have amended the question

Comment: So now I don't understand what you were trying to do with PIVOT??

Comment: I thought the Pivot was suitable and later realized that its not the best. Hopefully you understand this. How can I arrive to what am looking for?

Comment: See my Edit with no PIVOT and with separate SELECTs

Comment: Thanks Jonathan, will try your method and update you

Comment: I think the inserts are going to be painful, remember I mentioned that this table has more than 1000 records and the more I test the functions the more the table grows. So I don't think the insert will work here? Do you get my point?

Comment: It only does the inserts on the DISTINCT number of function names, so 100 odd.  That should not be a problem